# Android opengl Tracer not working

Tags: android, opengl-es, profiling, adb, trace

I am trying to run the android opengl tracer tool: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html

I am trying to run it on a Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.2) with Eclipse Juno.
I have also tried to run it from tool\monitor.bat stand-alone.

The tracer prompts me for my application. When I press ok, it then starts up the application.

After 2 seconds, I get the following message:
"Unexpected error while setting trace options: Software caused connection abort: socket write error."

I've also noticed there's a bunch of developer options on the device, which deal with tracing. I've tried tinkering with them, to no avail.

I couldn't find any decent documentation for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my Galaxy Nexus to Android 4.1.2 using fastboot and the stock Google ROM and got this to work, so I believe that it's a regression with 4.1.2. I've opened a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53426